# Javascript: Multiple timers VS single timer

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

I have a simple question about Javascript timers and their performance but it really bugs me because I can't figure out the right way to do it.

Here is the problem: I have a special timing function that self corrects itself:

```
function setCorrectingInterval(func, delay) {
    if (!(this instanceof setCorrectingInterval)) {
        return new setCorrectingInterval(func, delay);
    }
    var target = Date.now() + delay;
    var self = this;
    function tick() {
        if (self.stopped) {
            return;
        }
        target += delay;
        func();
        setTimeout(tick, target - Date.now());
    }
    setTimeout(tick, delay);
}
```

Then, in my application I use this function n times to set n different timer variables. So if I have two timer variables I would use this function twice to set them. In the code bellow I execute first task every 1000ms and second task every 2000ms:

```
var firstTimer,
    secondTimer;

function startFirstTimer() {
    firstTimer = setCorrectingInterval(function() {
        console.log("First!");
    }, 1000);
}

function startSecondTimer() {
    secondTimer = setCorrectingInterval(function() {
        console.log("Second!");
    }, 2000);
}

startFirstTimer();
startSecondTimer();
```

In my angular application the need for multiple timing events grows and grows. So my (tempoprary) solution to this is to create new timer variables with new setTimeouts using the setCorrectingInterval function as mentioned above.

So I got thinking - wouldn't it be better (performance wise) to just have one single timer variable with one single setTimeout in which using if statements I would execute tasks that meet the condition, like this:

```
var timer;

function startTimer() {
    var counter = 1;
    timer = setCorrectingInterval(function() {
        console.log("First!");
        if (counter % 2 === 0) {
            console.log("Second!");
        }

        counter++;
    }, 1000);
}

startTimer();
```

( provided every tasks would repeat execution with delay that is multiple of 1000 )

Which approach is better and why? Any explanation is very much appreciated, thank you

Comment: You're basically just emulating what the browser is doing when it manages multiple timers. Let the browser do its job.

Comment: You can try TaskTimer https://github.com/onury/tasktimer for multiple timers on different intervals.